# Select only those record which is either matching or not present in another table

Tags: sql, subquery

Let's say there is a table A:

```
Name Class Number
A    1    50
B    2    30
C    3    20
A    1    10
```

And table B:

```
Name  Class Number
A     1     50
C     3     20
```

Where the primary key is the Name column.

Question

I would like to keep only records in table A that match one of the following condition:

- record from table A exists in table B and values are identical
- record from table A does not exist in table B

Expected Result

```
Name   Class Number
A      1     50     // kept because all values match record in table B
B      2     30     // kept because record doesn't exist in table B
C      3     20     // kept because all values match record in table B
```

Comment: Have you looked the [`OUTER JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this should do it:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from tableb b 
    where 
        a.name = b.name 
        and (a.class <> b.class or a.number <> b.number)
)
```

This phrases as: select records in table a for which no other record exists in table b with the same id and a different class or number.

Otherwise, we can also express the two conditions explicitly, like so:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from tableb b 
        where a.name = b.name and a.class = b.class and a.number = b.number
    )
    or not exists (
        select 1 from tableb b where a.name = b.name 
    )
```

Comment: Will try and keep you posted